# hadoop 1.2.1 causes set permission failed error in windows(cygwin)?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cygwin

I just downloaded hadoop version 1.2.1.  For my windows machine, but it shows set permission error on startup for both task-tracker and job-tracker and i searched for the solution, got this patch [patch for hadoop 1.2.1 7682 bug](https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win).

After using this patch it solved the problem of starting up job tracker and task tracker, but when running mapreduce program again it showed the same set permission error.

**Logs received:**

```
        14/06/23 11:17:47 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
    Patch for HADOOP-7682: Instantiating workaround file system
    14/06/23 11:17:47 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    14/06/23 11:17:48 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    14/06/23 11:17:48 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
    14/06/23 11:17:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201406231107_0001
    14/06/23 11:17:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
    14/06/23 11:18:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201406231107_0001_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
    Error initializing attempt_201406231107_0001_m_000002_0:
    java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-adarshau\mapred\local\taskTracker\adarshau to 0700
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:514)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:349)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.createLocalDirs(JobLocalizer.java:144)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:191)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1336)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1311)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1226)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2603)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```